# Change colour of ALL text depending on one value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, colors

I'm trying to print all items in a dictionary and change the text colour dependant on the data in one value (Red for Fire / Blue for Water etc)

But instead of the whole dictionary, I can only get it to print the key:value pair for the single item containing that text.

Name: Nina The Cat
Type: Fire
Special Move: Purring
Starting HP: 50
Starting MP: 50

```
for key, value in my_dictionary.items():  
  if my_dictionary[key] == "Fire":  
    print (f"\033[33m{key}: \033[31m{value}")  
    #Key = Yellow , Value = Red
```

Type: Fire

Comment: `if my_dictionary['Type'] == "Fire":` ?

Comment: Step through your code. You only tell it to print if the value for the current key is 'Fire', which occurs only once if at all.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if `my_dictionary['Type'] == "Fire"` and decide the colors *before* you start printing all the key-value pairs. In the loop, format these colors into your string to print in addition to the key and value

```
if my_dictionary['Type'] == "Fire":  
    color_key = "\033[33m"
    color_val = "\033[31m"
else:
    color_key = # insert reset color code here
    color_val = # and here


for key, value in my_dictionary.items():  
    print(f"{color_key}{key}: {color_val}{val}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this solution will help you in solving your problem.

```
my_dictionary = {
    'Fire': 'Red',
    'Water': 'Blue'
}

colors = {
    'Red': '\033[31m',
    'Blue': '\033[34m'
}

key_color = '\033[33m'
for key, value in my_dictionary.items():
    print(f"{key_color + key}: {colors[value] + value}")
```